# C# iterate through multiple xml nodes (and subnodes) and write to a object

Tags: c#, xml, iteration, nodes

I´ve got a class Person (Name, Adress, Car, List) and a XML-Document with these values:

```
<person>
  <Name>Miller</name>
  <Car>BMW</car>
</person>
<person>
  <name>Smith</name>
  <adress>New York</adress>
  <Pets>
    <pet>Cat</pet>
    <pet>Dog</pet>
  </pets>
</person>....
```

How can I iterate through these nodes and subnodes (and subnodes if avail, and subnodes....) and write it all to my List?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using xmlwriter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xml linq.  You can load from a file by replacing the Parse() method with Load() method   :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication42
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
              "<Root>" +
              "<person>" +
                "<name>Miller</name>" +
                "<car>BMW</car>" +
              "</person>" +
              "<person>" +
                "<name>Smith</name>" +
                "<address>New York</address>" +
                "<pets>" +
                  "<pet>Cat</pet>" +
                  "<pet>Dog</pet>" +
                "</pets>" +
              "</person>" +
              "</Root>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            Person.people = doc.Descendants("person").Select(x => new Person() {
                name = (string)x.Element("name"),
                car = (string)x.Element("car"),
                address = (string)x.Element("address"),
                pets = x.Descendants("pet").Select(y => (string)y).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }

    }
    public class Person
    {
        public static List<Person> people { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string car { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public List<string> pets { get; set; }
    }


}
```